# can my parents register for admob instead of me but use my bank account to receive the money

Tags: admob

I couldn't register for admob with my email because am 17 and admob requires individuals 18 and above so it possible to register with my parents info and put my bank account to receive the money.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about parents

Comment: @Alex its about using admob so its not off-topic. am asking because am 17 and admob requires 18 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer, but I think this would be fine as long as it is your parents that are registering not you. Ie they are registering on your behalf and are willing to wear any fallout from misbehaviour on your part.